# Vue.js скрывать navbar по скроллу

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть следующий компонент:

```html
<template>
  <div class="header">
    Header content
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {

  }
</script>
<style>
  .header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Вопрос: каким образом добавить класс `header-hidden` к `div.header`, если высота скролла > 200px? Где во vue лучше вешать обработчики `window.on`? И нужно ли их уничтожать при уничтожении элемента?

Comment: В компоненте VueJs, Вы можете делать все то, что делали бы в нативном JS. Где удобно назначать обработчик, там это и делайте. При удалении компонента, если обработчик не нужен, то его желательно удалить - из соображений производительности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для корректной работы обработчик лучше всего разместить в блоке `mounted` или `created`. В блоке `destroyed` его следует удалить.

```
<template>
  <div ref="header" class="header">
    Header content
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  mounted(){
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
  },
  methods: {
    onScroll() {
      if (window.pageYOffset > 200) {
        this.$refs.header.classList.add('header-hidden');
      }
    },
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
  }
</script>
```